# Can we send mails from localhost using asp.net and c#?

Tags: c#, email, smtpclient

i am using `using System.Net.Mail;`

and following code to send mail

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

        // Set the sender's address
        message.From = new MailAddress("fromAddress");

     // Allow multiple "To" addresses to be separated by a semi-colon
        if (toAddress.Trim().Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (string addr in toAddress.Split(';'))
            {
                message.To.Add(new MailAddress(addr));
            }
        }
      // Allow multiple "Cc" addresses to be separated by a semi-colon
        if (ccAddress.Trim().Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (string addr in ccAddress.Split(';'))
            {
                message.CC.Add(new MailAddress(addr));
            }
        }
        // Set the subject and message body text
        message.Subject = subject;
        message.Body = messageBody;

        // Set the SMTP server to be used to send the message
        client.Host = "YourMailServer";

        // Send the e-mail message
        client.Send(message);
```

for Host i am providing `client.Host = "localhost";`

for this its falling with error

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it *some_ip_address_here*

and when i use `client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";`

i get following error

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond

i am not able to send mail through localhost.
Please help me out, i am new to c# please correct me in code where i am going wrong..?

Comment: You need an SMTP server that is willing to send mail for you.  (and a login, and the correct port & SSL settings)

Comment: how can i send mails from my machine, i am not deploying code. I am working on localhost.When i use host "smtp.gmail.com"; its faling..i don't know how to correct port and SSL settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is some code that works for sending mail via gmail (code from somewhere here on stackoverflow. It is similar to the code here: [Gmail: How to send an email programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1326027/246622)):

```
using (var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
{
  Credentials = new NetworkCredential("yourmail@gmail.com", "yourpassword"),
  EnableSsl = true
})
{
  client.Send("frommail@gmail.com", "tomail@gmail.com", "subject", message);
}
```

Comment: If you found the code somewhere, could you link to the original?

Comment: Yes. The problem is that I found it somewhere here some time ago and then have been using it for a while and now I do not remember the exact source.

Answer (score 2):

For sending mail from `client.Host = "localhost"` you need set up local SMTP server.

For sending mail via Google (or via any other SMTP server, including your own local SMTP) you must set username, password, ssl settings - all as required by SMTP server chosen, and you need to read their help for this.

For example Google [says](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=176600) that you need SSL, port 465 or 587, server `smtp.gmail.com` and your username and password.

You can assign all this values in .config file.

```xml
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp>
      <network host="smtp.gmail.com" enableSsl="true" port="587" userName="yourname@gmail.com" password="password" />
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Or set to SmtpClient in code before every use:

```
client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
client.Port = 587;
client.EnableSSL = true;
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("yourname@gmail.com", "password");
```

Answer (score 1):

Place this code inside a `<configuration> </configuration>` in web.config file

```xml
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp>
    <network host="smtp.gmail.com" enableSsl="true" port="587" userName="youremail@gmail.com" password="yourpassword" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

then backend code

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
message.From = new MailAddress("email@gmail.com");
message.To.Add(new MailAddress(TextBoxEadd.Text));
message.CC.Add(new MailAddress("email@gmail.com"));
message.Subject = "New User Registration ! ";
message.Body =  "HELLO";
sr.Close();
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Send(message);
```

I hope this code help you! :)

Comment: This worked for me! but can you tell me why you need to define message.From = new MailAddress("email@gmail.com") when you specify your credentials in the web config ie userName="youremail@gmail.com"

Answer (score 0):

use this Line..Dont Use Port And HostName

LocalClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.PickupDirectoryFromIis;

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add that Gmail now requires App Password in order to use it from other applications. Check this [link](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?visit_id=637171678046576707-3535355093&rd=1#ts=3202254,3202256). I had to find it the hard way. After I created an App Password and then I changed the NetworkCredentials to use it to send emails.