# Send e-mail using c#

Tags: c#, smtp

Can't understand why this code is not working. error message is **The operation has timed out**

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.ipage.com", 465);
client.EnableSsl = true;

client.Timeout = 50000;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(email, password);
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.To.Add(txtTo.Text.Trim());
msg.From = new MailAddress(email);
msg.Subject = txtSubject.Text.Trim();
msg.Body = txtMsg.Text.Trim();
//txtAttachment.Text = fileName.ToString();
Attachment attachment = new Attachment(txtAttachment.Text);
msg.Attachments.Add(attachment);
client.Send(msg);
MessageBox.Show("Successfuly sent Message.");
clear();
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the right SMTP addresss and port?

Comment: yes,connection security is SSL\TLS. thunderbird send mails oki...but code is not working.

Comment: try using the IP address instead, DNS could be working improperly.

Answer (score 0):

You may be getting a Null Reference Exception when adding the "To" email address. You may need to initialize the "To" MailAddressCollection.

```
msg.To = new MailAddressCollection();
msg.To.Add(txtTo.Text.Trim());
```

aslo there is some useful info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600563/what-ports-does-a-system-net-mail-smtpclient-need-with-smtpclient-enablessl) on stackoverflow about sending SmtpClient.EnableSSL = true messages using certain ports.